# Return empty string if string is 0 in SQL

Tags: sql

What could I do if, say I do this:

```
SELECT name as "cname" from dba
```

But if the value of name is '0' I want cname to be = to an empty "" string.

What could I use, in standard sql to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a CASE;

```
SELECT 
  case name when '0' then '' else name end as "cname" 
from dba
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a case statement:

```
SELECT CASE name WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE name END AS cname from dba
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a case statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name='0' THEN '' ELSE name END AS cname FROM dba
```